# Subscripts in matplotlib window title (figure num)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to write a subscript in the window title (`plt.figure(num='Window title')`). I tried with the standard format for matplotlib mathematical expressions but it doesn't interpret it like it does for other texts:

```
plt.figure('$Something_{subscript}$')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The window title of a GUI application has nothing to do with matplotlib. You may check in how far the GUI application would support markup. Usually unicode is supported, hence something like `plt.figure(u'H\u2082SO\u2084')` would work and result in

[image]